# Sort Vimeo API Showcase by custom order

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using a call

```
$response = $client->request("/users/$client_id/albums/$showcase_id/videos", array(), 'GET');
```

so I can add the sorting parameters for instance `?sort=alphabetical&direction=desc` but what I need is what Vimeo in the Showcase editor describe as 'custom' but `?sort=custom&direction=desc` is not a valid call.

How do I obtain the sorting order from the drag and drop?

Answer (score 1):

The various sort options are defined in [the API docs](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/showcases#get_showcase_videos), but I think the keyword you're looking for is `manual`. From the docs:

> manual - Sort the results by their manual order.

Comment: Definitely the correct answer, thank you.
`/users/$client_id/albums/$showcase_id/videos?sort=manual`